# PIG - concatenating a string to a parameter?

Tags: hadoop, grid, apache-pig

I have a pig script similar to the following:

```
a = LOAD 'feedname.hourly_data' 
USING org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
b = FILTER a BY dt=='$date{00}';
c = GROUP b ALL;
d = FOREACH c GENERATE COUNT(b); 
dump d;
```

The script is executed with the following arguments:

```
pig -useHCatalog -p date=20140708 my_script.pig
```

Note that this script works with dt value hardcoded:

```
a = LOAD 'feedname.hourly_data' 
USING org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
b = FILTER a BY dt=='2014070800';
c = GROUP b ALL;
d = FOREACH c GENERATE COUNT(b); 
dump d;
```

However, when I execute after passing the `date=20140708` parameter, the query will return zero results. Does anyone know why this is happening? If there isn't enough information to tell, what is the first thing that I should test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [use the `-dryrun` option](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.1/cont.html#Parameter-Sub) to see what your script looks like after parameter substitution. That will tell you if you are filtering as you expect to be.

It appears that Pig can't handle a parameter inside a string when it's not followed by a character illegal in parameter names (like `/`). Instead, in your case you should be able to use `CONCAT`:

```
b = FILTER a BY dt==CONCAT('$date', '00');
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the dryrun option would do that. Looking at the substitution output, my `'$date{00}'` expands to `'20140708{00}'`, which is wrong. Doing `b = FILTER a BY dt==${date}00;` as suggested doesn't work, though - pig complains with `Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near '$'` I also tried `b = FILTER a BY dt=='${date}00';`, but the it doesn't expand `${date}00`.

Comment: Bummer. I suggested a different alternative for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried that, and it gives me a memory error (ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. GC overhead limit exceeded) I have also tried `%default MIN_DATE \`echo ${date}00\`
%default MAX_DATE \`echo ${date}23\`` with no success (echo outputs `00` and `23` respectively)

Comment: You can run your script with the value hardcoded but when using `CONCAT` like above, you get a GC limit error?

Comment: That is correct. I am not sure how pig handles filtering / garbage collection - perhaps it's performing that CONCAT too many times? Is there a way to do something like: `%default MIN_DATE CONCAT('$date','00')`? (tried it but $MIN_DATE turns into 'CONCAT('$date','00')')

Comment: It sounds like you might just want to wrap your Pig script in a bash script and construct the parameter there.